# RollupError: "XhrIo" is not exported by "node_modules/@firebase/webchannel- wrapper/dist/index.js"

Tags: typescript, firebase, bundle, es6-modules, rollup

Here's the complete error message :

```
[!] RollupError: "XhrIo" is not exported by "node_modules/@firebase/webchannel-
wrapper/dist/index.js", imported by "node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.esm2017.js"
```

I am using `rollup` (`3.8.1`) to bundle my TypeScript webapp. My webapp uses `firebase` (`9.15.0`).
But as you can see when I try to bundle, `firestore` esm index tries to import an object from `@firebase/webchannel-wrapper` which resolves to the main index and not the module-typed one.

Looking into `@firebase/webchannel-wrapper/package.json` :

```json
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "module": "dist/index.esm2017.js",
  "esm5": "dist/index.esm.js",
```

Nothing's wrong with the value of "module", so my guess is that the problem is in rollup (or `@rollup/plugin-node-resolve`) resolution function.

I tried different things but I can't find the problem.

My app doesn't do anything fancy yet :

```js
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore'

...

// Initialize Firebase
export const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
export const db = getFirestore(firebaseApp)
```

My `tsconfig.json` :

```json
  "target": "es2022",
  "module": "esnext",
  "moduleResolution": "node"
```